# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to query the database where date is between today and yesterday but am getting error saying Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

My query is below with my parameters today and yesterday

```
string today = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        string yesterday= new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");


        string errorsPerHourQuery = "WITH data_CTE(ErrorDay)" +
                    "AS(" +
                    "SELECT DATEPART(hh, Date) AS ErrorDay FROM cloud.ErrorLog " +
                    "WHERE Date BETWEEN '@yesterday' AND '@today' " +
                    "AND  CAST(Message AS varchar(200)) ='@message'"+
                    ")" +
                    "SELECT ErrorDay, COUNT(*) AS count FROM data_CTE GROUP BY ErrorDay ORDER BY ErrorDay";

conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@message", message);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yesterday", yesterday);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@today", today);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
```

Comment: Remove ticks (`'`) from around your named parameters so that your query reads `...BETWEEN @yesterday and @today...` and you'll be all set.

Comment: The way this is written you are trying to cast the string literals to dates which will always fail.

Comment: Since you are using pass through sql and not a procedure you really need to read this article. AddWithValue will sometimes get the datatypes wrong. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/ You need to explicitly define the datatypes when using pass through queries like this.

Comment: Why are you converting your dates to strings? Just leave them as dates and remove the ' from @ yesterday and @ today and it should run.

Comment: the query doesn't seem to be working when I get rid of the ticks, it doesn't return anything

Comment: when I remove the ticks ' and leave today and yesterday as dates it doesn't return anything

Comment: @AntonGogolev God bless you, druzhiwe! I got mad while I was looking for a reason of this god damn exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must remove simple cote `'` from parmeters in query :

```
..BETWEEN @yesterday AND @today
```

You don't need to create today and yesterday with specific format, you can simply get variable like :

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
```

and use Parameter with `SqlDbType.DateTime` and then pass the DateTime directly to the parameter (do not need to convert).

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@yesterday", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = yesterday
cmd.Parameters.Add("@today", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = today
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you're calculating your `today` and `yesterday` wrong. Here's the correct way:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;
var yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);
```

And regaring query: remove ticks (`'`) from around your named parameters so that your query reads `...BETWEEN @yesterday and @today...` and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are quoting your command parameters which is getting considered as string literal instead of parameter as seen below.

```
WHERE Date BETWEEN '@yesterday' AND '@today'
```

You should change it to

```
WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @yesterday AND @today
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of good points in the other answers especially.  @Abdellah does a good job of teaching the `datetime` datatype and the appropriate value, but your SQL query itself needs work and may be why you are not getting what you want.  Because just like the `@yesterday` and `@today` you need to remove the ''(ticks) from `@message`.  Then you can do your query in 1 step you don't need the cte.  Plus if you aren't going to pass any dates other than yesterday or today there is no need for parameters use SQL's built in functions.

So remove all of the ticks around all of your parameters (@yest...)

Here is a SQL query that should work for you:

```
SELECT
    ErrorHour = DATEPART(HH,[Date])
    ,[Count] = COUNT(*)
FROM
    cloud.ErrorLog
WHERE
    --use this line from midnight yesterday to midnight today
    CAST([Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(GETDATE() - 1) AND CAST(GETDATE())

    --what is the datatype for message does it really need to be cast?
    AND CAST([Message] AS VARCHAR(200)) = @Message
GROUP BY
    DATEPART(HH,[Date])
ORDER BY
    ErrorHour
```

Note I put `ErrorHour` you are welcome to change to `ErrorDay`, but you are counting errors per hours not days, to change what you are counting simply change your `DATEPART()` to be the time component you want, e.g. minutes, etc..

Next Do you really need to cast Message field?

On the dates.  Are you wanting everything today and yesterday or really just yesterday? If just yesterday swap this line into the query for the other date line:

--if you really just want yesterday midnight to 11:59:59 PM the it should be
CAST([Date] AS DATE) = CAST(GETDATE()-1 AS DATE)

Next if you really really want to pass yesterday and today as parameters and you want all of yesterday and all of today do the following and update your parameter definitions in your code as the other posts suggest.

--use this line from midnight yesterday to midnight today
CAST([Date] AS DATE) BETWEEN CAST(@yesterday AS DATE) AND CAST(@Today AS DATE)